# Altering table using the Symfony2 Doctrine2 console/generate feature?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

What I'm trying to figure out is how to add new fields to a table, using Symfony2 with Doctrine2.

I used this to initially create the Entity:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="MyMainBundle:ImagesTable" --fields="title:string(100) file:string(100)"
```

And I used this to create/update the tables on the database:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Now if I wanted to add new fields to the `ImagesTable` entity, is there an easy way to do it using the `console`, or do I have to manually edit the entity. I am just using 1 entity as an example right now, but in reality, there are many entities I'd be changing; so, there has to be an easier way to do it.

I've been manually editing them to create relationships, so if there is an easier way to do that as well, that'd be great.

I remember this being a lot easier with Symfony1.4 - all I had to do was create the database/tables using phpMyAdmin, and Symfony was able to generate the models with no issues.

I really hope I'm missing something here, because this won't work if I have to manually edit every entity for every change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine generator commands are intended to help the developer to quickly prototype an idea. They generally don't produce production ready code, and the code needs to be checked to see if it contains what you want.

You can still create your model in phpmyadmin and use [Doctrine reverse engineering tools](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering), but it also doesn't produce production ready code, only intended to use in prototyping.

Creating database/tables beforehand doesn't really work well with Doctrine2, as the underlying relation between tables may not be the same as the relation between objects of your model. The whole point of ORM is to think in classes and letting Doctrine do the rest of the work for you.

Doctrine is not intended to write your entities for you, it gives you tools to build your data model, which you use to code your model in Php.

If you don't like to code your entities by hand (which is what all developers using doctrine does), you may want to have a look at [RedbeanPHP](http://redbeanphp.com/), a zero-config ORM framework for PHP. It creates the database tables, columns, indexes on the fly depending on the data model you use.

Comment: I'm not saying that I want it to generate absolutely everything, but I do expect it to generate the basics (setters and getters). I shouldn't have to manually sit there an enter setters and getters for like 15 different fields (if I plan on altering the table/entity later). I think you've missed my point here...

Comment: There is a [generate entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#entity-generation) command for console, but again, it just generates the basic setters and getters. Depending on how much logic you want to include in your entities, it may not be the solution. And it doesn't generate correct entities for inheritance.

Comment: Yes I know, but my original question asked if there was a command to add fields to an existing entity. Otherwise, I have to manually add each field (property & getter/setter). Or, I guess I could delete the entity and re-generate it, but I don't see that as an optimal solution.

Comment: There isn't and command for that. You can add a new property manually, and use generate entities command for getter and setter methods for the new property. The command doesn't deletes anything, and adds the new getter/setter when it finds the new property. But if you use inheritance in your model, it will mess up the inherited classes. There isn't really an fully working automated solution for this. Generate entities command only helps you with the basics.

Comment: With doctrine way, it's better to think and build your data model upfront, and make the changes manually afterwards. Before coding my data model in doctrine, I try to build my data model on paper, refactoring it to my needs. I build it with doctrine when I'm satisfied with it. Ofcourse, I need to change it during development when some unforeseeable relation pops up, or when I need to add more features, but it's not really hard to modify it. Many IDEs and editors allows you to use snippets to add generic code quickly and efficiently, which I use for generating setters and getters quickly.

Comment: As I said in the answer, if you don't like to design your data model upfront, and instead design it incrementally, figuring out the details along the way, RedbeanPHP is the perfect solution. That's the main reason why it's developed in the first place. You may use it to quickly prototype the model, and convert to doctrine when you finish, but it won't be really efficient either.

Comment: Thank you @Hakan - your answers have been helpful.